# Linkedin Share Plugin always displays 0 shares

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using the Linkedin Share Plugin https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share

It always seems to display 0 no matter what URL I enter (ie http://linkedin.com or http://salesforce.com)
It has been like this since 2:45 PM EST Thursday (January 11).

Is there a bug with it currently?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, please update here if you found anything, thanks

Comment: I am using this endpoint:  https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url={url}&format=json

Comment: We're seeing this for all the URLs we're testing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinkedIn share count API (/countserv/count/share) always returns "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282250/linkedin-share-count-api-countserv-count-share-always-returns-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This API has been end-of-lifed unfortunately:

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2018/deprecating-the-inshare-counter

There is no alternative solution being offered by Linkedin (at least not yet).

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedIn share counts are back.](https://twitter.com/AddToAny/status/953774770864013312) Their API is returning non-zero counts again, for example:

https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F

According to AddToAny, LinkedIn was "running a test to determine the effectiveness of the share count number on the inShare button."

LinkedIn should really improve their developer relations.

Comment: Looks like the problem is back :(